# Certify using Yubikey

Tags: certificates, digital-signature, x.509, smartcard, yubikey

I just started using a Yubikey 5. I've set up GPG according to [this excellent guide](https://github.com/drduh/YubiKey-Guide), and now I have [3 working ECC key pairs on my Yubikey](https://rgoulter.com/blog/posts/programming/2022-06-10-a-visual-explanation-of-gpg-subkeys.html#visualisation-of-the-offline-master-key-setup): Sign/S :: *ed25519*, Encrypt/E :: *cv25519*, Authentication/A :: *ed25519*.

Now I want to use my Yubikey to certify other keys. The private GPG primary key, the only one with Certify/C is not available on the Yubikey. The other choice is the PIV (smartcard) module, this has [4 keypair slots](https://developers.yubico.com/PIV/Introduction/Certificate_slots.html) but no Certify key neither (or are C keys only a designation in GPG?). So:

- Should I use a signing key (from either GPG or PIV) for certification?
- Or, is certification through a hardware key not adviced at all (for some practical security reasons)?

---

**Background:** I had the idea of using the PIV module for SSH (which has to be slot 9a: *PIV Authentication*). Each of the 4 slots [needs a X.509 certificate](https://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/FIPS/NIST.FIPS.201-3.pdf#section*.109) (i.e. a certified keypair). Therefore I need to certify each of the four X.509 certificates, and I wanted Yubikey to do that certification (signing). By using certified SSH keys, I could configure my server to do [certificate authentification](https://goteleport.com/blog/how-to-configure-ssh-certificate-based-authentication/#configuring-ssh-for-user-certificate-authentication). It turns out that [Yubico's FIDO2](https://developers.yubico.com/SSH/Securing_SSH_with_FIDO2.html) is an easier way to use Yubico for SSH.

**Edit:** Turns out that Yubico suggests using self signed X.509 certificates for PIV: https://developers.yubico.com/PIV/Guides/SSH_user_certificates.html, that is, they use their generated certificates as the certifier for itself. Does this mean that I could also certify the PIV's 4 certificates (or SSH keys in general) using the Sign/S keypair of my Yubico's GPG module? Which signer would you suggest then?